# regex - Java Regular expression matching square bracket

Tags: java, regex, match

Would someone kindly demonstrate what the regular expession would be for matching the square brackets?

I'm currently using `java.util.regex`.

For example, let's say we have the following line:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
```

I need to match only the OPEN square bracket `[` and next, the close square bracket `]`.

I'm not saying I need to match the text between the square brackets.

I have tried with

```
[\\]]
```

and

```
\\]
```

Unfortunately, it matches the text as well and I need to match only `[` or `]`.

The weird thing is, when I try to match the `{` with `[\\}]`, it works!

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you try `[\[\]]`?

Comment: I'm seeing confusion here about basic regex concepts.  Please edit your question and show us exactly what you are trying to match.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.  Some characters need to be escaped with backslash in a regex, and then the backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash in string literals.  It's hard to tell whether you're getting it right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282947/regular-expression-to-match-string-within-a-square-bracket

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using:

```
    String text = "[This is the text]";

    String patternString = "\\[.*.\\]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    System.out.println("Matcher? " + matcher.matches());
```

This return true if the text has a `[` and `]` and false if it doesn't

Hope this can help you.
Thanks.